# Stored procedure to add 30 days using DATEDIFF within while loop condition in Date Dimension table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, while-loop, datediff

I want to add 30 consecutive days of data in my Date Dimension table using DATEDIFF() but I am getting blank result. Can you please help me correct the code below to get the desired result?

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.dateDimension (
    DateKey INT NOT NULL
    ,DateValue DATE NOT NULL
    ,CYear SMALLINT NOT NULL
    ,CMonth TINYINT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_DimDate PRIMARY KEY ( DateKey )
);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.dateTest 
@StartDate DATETIME
AS
WHILE (DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, GETDATE()) <=30)
BEGIN
    INSERT into dbo.dateDimension
    SELECT CAST( YEAR(@StartDate) * 10000 + MONTH(@StartDate) * 100 + DAY(@StartDate) AS INT)
    ,@StartDate
    ,YEAR(@StartDate)
    ,MONTH(@StartDate)
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate)
END;
GO

EXECUTE dbo.dateTest '2010-01-01'
SELECT * FROM dbo.dateDimension
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that this logic:

```
DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, GETDATE())
```

gives 3739 days with your current start date, so its never less than 30. Personally I would simply count it as follows:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2010-01-01', @Count INT = 0;

WHILE @Count <= 30 BEGIN
    INSERT into dbo.dateDimension
    SELECT CAST( YEAR(@StartDate) * 10000 + MONTH(@StartDate) * 100 + DAY(@StartDate) AS INT)
        , @StartDate
        , YEAR(@StartDate)
        , MONTH(@StartDate);
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(d,1,@StartDate);
    set @Count = @Count + 1;
END;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.dateDimension;
```

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah that was a stupid logic, shouldn't be a getdate. Thanks for pointing out. It works.

Comment: Is there any way we can just mention the number of years, for which we want to accomplish the same task. Say 2 years?

Comment: @Vers thats a separate question, so ask a new one, rather than adding it onto this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or above, this solution will not use a while loop, instead it uses a CTE to generate 30 rows numbered I to 30 and then uses the date to convert to `yyyymmdd`.

```
DECLARE @NUM_DAYS INT=30;
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME='2020-01-01';

WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS SRL
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLICATE(',',@num_days-1), ',') AS A
) 
INSERT INTO dbo.dateDimension
SELECT 
    CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY, SRL-1, @STARTDATE), 112))
    , @STARTDATE
    , YEAR(@STARTDATE)
    , MONTH(@STARTDATE)
FROM CTE

SELECT * FROM dbo.dateDimension
```

Comment: While works for me but wanted to optimize. But thank you for sharing another way of doing it using CTE. This works too.

Comment: Is there any way we can just edit the number of years, for which we want to accomplish the same task. Say 2 years?

Comment: If I understood your question, you need to generate the required number of records in the CTE. i.e. for 2 years, you can SET @NUM_DAYS = 2 * 365.

Comment: yeah but we have to take leap year into consideration also so 2*365 won't help there

Comment: You can DATEADD 2 years to the STARTDATE and then get the Num_Days using the DATEDIFF between the calculated date and the STARTDATE.